# How can I download comments on a webpage (Android)

Tags: java, android, download, connection

Usually I use this code to download a webpage source:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://mysite.com/index.html");
StringBuffer all = new StringBuffer("");                                                

URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();              
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream(); 


BufferedReader page = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-15"));   


while((linea = page.readLine()) != null){        
        all.append(linea.trim()); 
}
```

It works fine with a wifi connection because it downloads the string like `<!-- it's a comment -->,`but i tried to used a mobile connection with my mobile phone but it doesn't download the comments.. Is there a method to include the comments on download webpage source?

thx for reply ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your service provider is compressing the pages on their side to reduce the data sent. I've not heard of this being done for HTML but it is frequently done for JPG, so it's easy to image that's what's happening. This compression would be very likely to remove comments.

It would be nice if there was some http convention to tell the stack 'never compress', but (at fas as I know) there is not. So you're probably out of luck.